# why do my ssh sessions freeze after some time?

Tags: ssh

Apologies if this is not the right place for asking this question.

I regularly need to ssh to different servers.
Now, from my home machine (linux mint), when I connect via ssh, after some time of inactivity, my ssh shell freezes, and there's no way to get it back. The only thing I can do is '~.", that at least gives me my initiating shell back.

When I login from other locations to the same servers there's no issue.
Could that be a problem with my ISP?
How can I investigate further on this one?

It's really annoying, as I have to re-establish ssh connections after the freeze, navigate back to where I was and resume work. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a static IP address ? If not it could be that your ISP has given you a different IP address mid session - check your logs and see.

Comment: I don't have a static IP address. Will check

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your NAT is dropping your TCP socket after a period of inactivity.

Your ssh client can optionally send periodic noops to the server, thereby eliminating this problem. To do this, add this to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Alternatively, re-configure your NAT to not expire items out of its state table as quickly as it is now.

---

In addition to the above, you should be using a terminal multiplexer for your sessions - something like GNU Screen or tmux. With either of those, you can recover your session in the event of getting disconnected.

Comment: Either the NAT or any painfully wrong firewall in the path which likes to drop idle TCP sessions. There's no reason to drop idle TCP sessions, besides lack of memory to keep states but that should happen very seldomly if you correctly size and configure your equipments. It's a good feature to know if your provider/admin is competent (or not).

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in large MTU size. You can change MTU on router if you using NAT, but I change MTU on server:

```
sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 mtu 1036
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

On Windows you can also increase this key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"TcpMaxDataRetransmissions"=dword:00000010
```